# fastest way to process csv, bash vs php vs c/c++ speed for processing

Tags: php, python, c++, c, bash

I have a csv with 5M rows. I have an option to import them at mysql database
and then loop the table with php.

```
db_class=new MysqlDb;
$db_class->ConnectDB();
$query="SELECT * FROM mails WHERE .....";
$result=mysqli_query(MysqlDb::$db, $query);
while($arr=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    //db row here 
}
```

So I loop all the mails from the the table and process them. IF they contain some bad string, I delete them etc.

This works but is very slow to import 5M rows, is also very slow to loop all of them one by one  and edit the rows (delete when they contain bad string).

I am thinking of a better solution for skipping php/mysql at all. I will process the .csv file, line by line and check if the current row contains a specific bad string. I can do that In pure php, like:

```
$file = file('file.csv');
while (($data = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
  //process line
   $data[0];
}
```

This is the bash script I use to loop all lines of a file

```
while read line; do    
    sed -i '/badstring/d' ./clean.csv
done < bac.csv
```

While on python I do

```
with open("file.csv", "r") as ins:
    array = []
    for line in ins:
      //process line here
```

A bad line would be like

```
name@baddomain.com
name@domain (without extension)
```

etc I have a few criterias for what a bad line is, thats why I didn't bother posting it here.

However for very big files I must try to find a better solution. What do you guys recommend? Should I learn how to do it in c/c++ or bash. Bash I know a little already, so I can make it faster. Is c/+++ much faster than bash for this situation? OR I should stick with bash?

Thank you

Comment: *»if the current row contains a specific bad string«*. The best solution depends on what exactly a bad string is. If bad strings can be identified by a simple regex I would use a single `grep` call inside bash or any other shell. Please post a small example file before and after deleting bad rows.

Comment: Instead of reading all lines into memory, consider processing the file line-by-line in your C (++)  code. Since you haven't posted any relevant code, let me recommend Perl: `perl -MText::CSV_XS=csv -e 'open my $fh, '<', "file.csv" or die $!; my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new(); while (my $line = $csv->getline($fh) { ... })`. See [Text::CSV_XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS)

Comment: @Corion I mentioned I dont know c++. If I must learn it for this task, (if its worth it for the speed, I will do s0

Comment: PHP [The manual `fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) Read one row at a time rather than the whole file in one big gulp

Comment: In your `bash` script you are creating a new `sed` child process for each line - I don't see how that is necessary.  It certainly would give a performance hit.  Bear in mind that `bash` supports regular expressions and often the external `sed` language is unnecessary.  C or C++ might give  performance improvement, but there is no guarantee without measuring where the performance bottleneck is.  Use something like `strace` for that.  In general, C or C++ has to be well written and it is too easy to write poor code which creates more problems than it solves.

Comment: @Corion How can I install https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS? I am using atom.io with gpp compiler.

Comment: @cdarke Can you suggest a better solution in that simple 3 line bash code? I'm new to them. I just know php a bit more

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do in that loop, right now you reread the file and don't use `$line` anywhere.  I would suggest just the `sed` on its own without the loop around it - `sed` loops itself on each line anyway.  (`sed` has nothing to do with `bash` by the way, it's just that it is often invoked from `bash`).

Comment: @cdarke
I need to loop the entire file line by line, because I also have a file called bad.txt
which contains all the bad strigns a LINE SHOULD NOT HAVE. SO that's why I have to loop each line. Does that make sense

Comment: It would if that was what you were doing, but your are reading the same file with the loop as with `sed`.

Comment: @cdarke I edited it, I just put a dummy code there. Didn't realise I had put same file name on bash script. Can you do a c++ version for me? I can pay

Comment: @inrob:  that's not really what this site is for.  We don't know if C++ would give a better result without research on your data, and I'm not sure why you decided on C++ instead of, say, C.  You should understand the problem, i.e. where the performance bottleneck is, before deciding on the solution.

Comment: I thought c++ was easier than c, to make a quick code work was realy simple
iterate file line by line
if line contains bad string then remove it and save file
or remove it from array and save array to file at the end ALL I NEEDED :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for PHP solution, you are looking for [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php). The manual includes the example of iterating the CSV file.

Or, if you want to be fancy, you can go with [league/csv](https://csv.thephpleague.com/) library.

Comment: Thanks I know fgetscv, thanks !